# Check for identical elements in a table in Lua?

Tags: lua

How would you check a table for three identical elements (looking for three L's)?

```
table = {nil, nil, L, nil, L} -> false
table = {L, L, nil, nil, L} -> true
```

Really would appreciate some help!

EDIT: Ok I've got this, but it only outputs false even when there are three or more L's (and does so five times for every check?). Sorry if it seemed like I was trying to get the code for it, I'm genuinely trying to learn! :)

```
for k, v in pairs( threeL_table ) do
local count = 0
  if k == 'L' then
    count = count + 1
  end
  if count == 3 then
    print('true')
  else
    print('false')
  end
end
```

Comment: you should not use table as a table name as table is already an existing table, provided by Lua, that contains functions for table manipulation. if you asign a new value to table you won't be able to use those functions

Comment: @Piglet I know, it's just a way to show what I am looking for :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543754/how-to-check-the-repetition-from-lua-table-value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. You need to test the values `v` against `'L'`, not the keys `k`. Also, I suppose you want to print the message only once after the scan is concluded; if so, put the if-statement outside of the for-loop. (In this case, you should define `count` outside of the for-loop, too, otherwise you would not see it once it has ended).

```
local count = 0
for k, v in pairs( threeL_table ) do
  if v == 'L' then -- you need to check for the values not the keys
    count = count + 1
  end
end
if count == 3 then -- move this out of the for-loop
  print('true')
else
  print('false')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not give you any code as you did not show any own efforts to solve the problem.

How would you check a table for three identical elements? Well you count them.

Loop over the table and for every distinct value you create a new counter. You could use another table for that. Once one of those counters reaches 3 you know that you have three identical values.

Comment: Thanks for the start. I've got so far: 'for k, v in pairs( threeL_table ) do'
    'print(k, v)'
 'end' which prints either L or nothing.

Comment: If you could please refer to my edit that would be great! EDIT: Nevermind! I was comparing k and not v! Thanks so much for putting me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this.

```
function detectDup(t,nDup)
  table.sort(t)
  local tabCount = {}
  for _,e in ipairs(t) do
    tabCount[e] = (tabCount[e] or 0) + 1
    if tabCount[e] >= 3 then
      print("The element '" .. e .. "' has more than 3 repetitions!")
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end

print(detectDup({'L', 'L','A','B'},3))
print(detectDup({'L', 'L','A','B','L',},3))
```